# Dunford-Pettis for Banach-Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Can anyone tell me if the Dunford-Pettis property is met for a separate refelxive Banach space $X$ with dual $X'$?

I would say that this is the case.

Comment: [No.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunford%E2%80%93Pettis_property#Counterexamples)

Comment: This means, that the $L^p$-Space (for $1<p<\infty$) do not have we Dunford Pettis property. Is there a similar statement for such rooms?